# Can't access Model attributes during validation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, validation

I'm using Spring 3.1 and have web pages using validation.  The field-level validation, and the display of errors, works OK.  My problem is with Model attributes not being available during the validation form display.

Let's say I've code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/edit", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getEdit(@RequestParam("id") Long id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("mytitle", "Hello There");
    return "editObject"
}

@RequestMapping(value="/edit", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String postEdit(@RequestParam("id") Long id, @Valid @ModelAttribute("object") MyData object, BindingResult result) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return "editObject";
    }
    [snip]

}
```

If I have an error the hasErrors() is detected and short-circuits to the map "editObject".  However, the model attributes aren't available.

What do I use here?  I tried adding a Model reference to the postEdit parameter list and adding in again things like the "mytitle" attribute.

Thanks,
Jerome.

Comment: Which attributes are not available?

Comment: In my actual program I pass in some Java objects and use their values for display in a JSP page.  In the context of this example, the JSP web page would display the "mytitle" attribute.  When the JSP page is redisplayed to show the validation errors the "mytitle" isn't available for display.  Getting things like "mytitle" into the JSP page, in the context of handling the POST event, is my overall question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `postEdit` controller render the `editObject` view, you are in a new request, so you are loosing the `model` (previously set for `getEdit` action).

What you need to do it re-set any values needed in a new `model`:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/edit", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String postEdit(@RequestParam("id") Long id, @Valid @ModelAttribute("object") MyData object, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("mytitle", "Hello There");
        model.addAttribute("object", object);
        return "editObject";
    }
```

If you need to keep those attributes for different views you can store them in a session for example (so that you won't have to re-set them for each new request).

Comment: Yes, that is my needed answer.  One more thing I found that I needed -- when a global error needs to be displayed, put the <form:errors /> tag inside of the <form:form> tag.  Seems obvious once it is explained (I found the answer elsewhere in stackoverflow) but it took a while for the light to dawn on me.